# Given the elevation, find height using trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone help solve the following quickly please ?:

> - A surveyor standing on a horizontal plain can see a volcano i the distance.
> - The angle of elevation of the top of the volcano i $23$ degrees.
> - If the surveyor moves $750$ m closer, the angle of elevation is now $37$ degrees.

Determine the height of the volcano using trigonometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

By simple trigonometric rules, you need to solve the system for **h=height** and **d=distance**

$$\begin{cases}\frac{h}{d}=\tan 23°\\\\\frac{h}{d-750}=\tan 37°\end{cases}$$

[image]

Comment: We don't know height or range. Not sure how to solve it?

Comment: @maq we have 2 equation in 2 unknown, thus we can find a solution

Comment: @maq it should be h=729 m, check also by hand calculation http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx*tan+23%C2%B0,+y%3D(x-750)*tan+37%C2%B0